# How can I close navigation on click?

Tags: javascript, navigation, push

like in `this` example but close after you clik on nav item

https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/XmpMEp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach i took was to hook into the `click` event of each menu item.

When it's clicked you'll want to simulate the click on the hamburger close icon.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".nav.sidebar-nav a").forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.querySelector('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click();
    });
});
```

https://codepen.io/craigiswayne/pen/axRKME

Sure there are other approaches like hooking into Bootstrap events.

Comment: my html is based on refrence link. i just dont know how to modify js, so navbar would close on click, when clicking an item from navbar